# Get exception in web method when trying to assign value in page attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net

[When i'm trying to assign value in textbox through webmethod on my page i got this exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psm4i.jpg)

My HTML Code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"><br /><br />
<asp:ScriptManager ID="src" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>           
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <asp:Button ID="btnChangeMake" runat="server" Text="Change Make" OnClientClick="ChangeMake()"/><br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMake" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Javascript Code

```
function ChangeMake() {
PageMethods.ChangeMakeText("Devil", onSucess, onError);
function onSucess(result) {
    alert(result);
}
function onError(result) {
    alert(result);
}
```

}

C# Code

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ChangeMakeText(string DataValue)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        TextBox txtMake = (TextBox)page.FindControl("txtMake");
        txtMake.Text = DataValue;
    }
}
```

Exception at 'txtMake.Text = DataValue;'

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_0lr1r3rs.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: For a web method I don't think you can do like this

Comment: How can i call a c# method from javascript...

Comment: You could not access the controls in the web method rather you can send value back to calling method in javascript and assign it to txtMake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could not access the page controls in the web method** rather you can send value back to calling method in javascript and assign it to txtMake.

C# code

```
public static string ChangeMakeText(string DataValue)
{
    //Your code    
    return DataValue;
}
```

Javascript Code

```
function ChangeMake() {
     PageMethods.ChangeMakeText("Devil", onSucess, onError);
     function onSucess(result) {
          document.getElementById("<%=txtMake.ClientID%>").value = result;
     }
}
```

You have already used Ajax `UpdatePanel` so bind click event with button btnChangeMake (by double click it in desginer) and change the value in server side click handler.

```
void btnChangeMake_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     txtMake.Text = DataValue;
}
```